# Alternative to loop ifelse() for vector data

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, warnings

I have a price dataframe `dat` and a second dataframe with currencies `cur`. What i want to do is to transform every non-EUR price in `dat` into Euro with a `for()` function and nested `ifelse()`. `else` a price already is EUR, the function should do nothing and return the original value into the column `Price €` in `dat`.

dat:

```
Nation   Price  Price€  
AT       10
AT       12
BE       15
BG       30
BG       40
CZ       200
```

cur:

```
Nation Rate
BG     0.51
CZ     0.03918
```

Only countries with non-EU currency are contained in `cur`. 
I used this code:

```
 for (i in 1:length(cur)){
  if(dat$Nation == cur$Nation[i]){
    dat$Price * cur$Rate[i]
     }
     else { }
  }
```

The output should be something like this:

dat:

```
Nation  Price  Price€
AT      10     NA
AT      12     NA
BE      15     NA
BG      30     15.3
BG      40     20.4
CZ      200    7.836
```

The idea is to fill NAs in the `Price€` column (those are countries with € currency) - resulting from not telling the function what to do in the case of `else` -  with values from `Price` after the loop finished.

```
 index <- is.na(dat$Price€)
 dat$Price€[index] <- dat$Price[index]
```

dat:

```
Nation  Price  Price€
AT      10     10
AT      12     12
BE      15     15
BG      30     15.3
BG      40     20.4
CZ      200    7.836
```

My problem here is, that R gives an error message:

```
Warning messages:
1: In if (dat$Nation == cur$Nation[i]) { :
the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In if (dat$Nation == cur$Nation[i]) { :
the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

What it does is multiplying all price values with the first exchange rate (0.51) and then stopping to look for identical values for the columns `Nation` in both dataframes to apply a different exchange rate. This is just a simple example from my dataset. There are multiple entries for each country within the EU (n=1740).

This might sound a complicated way to do this, but I am new to R and would like to know how to fix this function or what an alternative function would be.

Cheers

Comment: For this case, you should merge your data and then calculate `Price€`. But you should also learn when to use the vectorized `ifelse()` rather than that one-at-a-time `if(){}else{}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you are comparing a vector against a character in `if (dat$Nation == cur$Nation[i])`, so the error tells you that it will only compare the first element of `dat$Nation` with `cur$Nation[i]`.

In R, for-loops are often not necessary (and slow). You could do for example the following:

```
dat$conv <- cur$Rate[match(dat$Nation,cur$Nation)] # add the conversion factor
dat$PriceE <- ifelse(is.na(dat$conv), dat$Price, dat$Price * dat$conv)
dat$conv <- NULL
```

Output:

```
  Nation Price PriceE
1     AT    10 10.000
2     AT    12 12.000
3     BE    15 15.000
4     BG    30 15.300
5     BG    40 20.400
6     CZ   200  7.836
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: OK, I understand the problem here. What does `match` in this case do?

When i try your code, this happens:
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "PriceE", value = logical(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 1738
In addition: Warning message:
In is.na(dat$conv) :
  is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'

Comment: Match looks up the corresponding index where cur$Nation is equal to dat$Nation, and this index is used to get the value for Rate. For the error, make sure that the column names are correct? If you renamed some for your example here

Comment: ok, i checked the names and had to change mode from factor to numeric (did not see that in the first place). Your recommendation works exactly the opposite way i would like to have it. € prices are returned into the new column but all other values are NAs

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be much easier as a merge/join operation. Using tidy verse you can do

```
library(tidyverse)
dat <- read_table("Nation   Price
AT       10
AT       12
BE       15
BG       30
BG       40
CZ       200")
cur <- read_table("Nation Rate
BG     0.51
CZ     0.03918")


dat %>% left_join(cur) %>% 
  mutate(Rate=coalesce(Rate, 1)) %>%
  mutate(EPrice = Price * Rate)
```

The only trick here is to change the Rate for those nations not in the `cur` table to 1.

Comment: When I try this, an error occurs: Error: `by` required, because the data sources have no common variables

Comment: In the sample data you provided (and in the sample data I included in this answer) both datasets have a `Nation` column. Did you run this with some other data to get that error?

Comment: Yes, i simplified the dataset in this case. Both datasets indeed have this column with identical names, its just not "Nation"

Comment: Then I’m guessing they are not as identical as you think they are. Hard to say without a reproducible example.

Comment: I checked it. the corresponding colum in cur is a factor. Try to change mode, but this
`cur$Nation <- as.numeric(as.character(cur$Nation))`
did not work